# Using JSON in Python to send query to MongoDB

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm trying to create the following query in Python for a connection I have to MongoDB.

```
db.deal.find({"id":"11223|14589"})
```

By using the writing the following code:

```
import json

unique_id = "11223|14589"

query = json.dumps({"id":"%s"}) %(unique_id)
```

Unfortunately, this creates a string, and the results I don't get any returned results from MongoDB. Querying manually using the string that is created in variable query actually returns results. Anyone know what I might do to get this working from pymongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

First of all, you should not have to serialize anything into JSON. Especially not replace parts of the string *after it's serialized*.

Second, is `unique_id` one value that you're looking for? If so, just pass it to the query:

```
unique_id = '11223|14589'
foo.find({'id': unique_id})
```

Or are these two values you'd like to search for?

```
unique_id = '11223|14589'
ids = unique_id.split('|') # ['11223', '14589']
foo.find({'id': {'$in': ids}})
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason when I was using the variable directly in the dict I wasn't getting the quoting I needed. Your solution worked.